# regular expressions: first match vs greedy match

Tags: regex, matlab, vertica

Consider the regular expression `\d*`

If I try to match this against the string `JJJ123`, Vertica's regex functions say it matches against the string of width zero at the beginning.

If  I try it instead in matlab, it reports a match starting at the character `1`.

The Vertica docs say that its regex engine is PCRE.  I can't find much on matlab's, though I found hints that it's similar to perl's.

Which of the behaviors is more standard for perl-like regex engine?

Comment: MATLAB starts indicies at 1. There is no such index as 0. It just "makes more sense!"

Comment: One regular expression engine forces the match to start at the beginning of the string (an implicit `$` preceeding the pattern). The other regular expression engine matches the pattern anywhere within the string. For reference, see the difference between Python's `re.search` and `re.match`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @tenub:  note that's character 1, not position 1.  @IceArdor:  No, Vertica isn't forcing the match to start at the beginning of the string.  Rather, it returns the empty string positioned at the beginning of the string because that's the first match, not because it was forced to.  Similarly, AFAICT Python's `re.search()` returns the same thing---the empty string at the beginning.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using for the match? When you say "character 1, not position 1", do you mean that Matlab is returning the number 4 to indicate matching '1' at the fourth position? That's what I get for `[a,b,c,d] = regexp('JJJ123', '\d*')` in Matlab R2014a. Which is surprising; the 0-length match at the beginning is expected for any of the regex dialects I know, and Matlab's `regexp` defines `*` to match `zero or more`.

Comment: @AndrewJanke:  yes, that's exactly what I mean, and the matlab function I'm using.  And your comment re dialects goes to the heart of my question:  is the matlab behavior standard, or Vertica's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab's `regexp` has an `emptymatch` option that controls whether it will allow an entire regex expression to match an empty string. It is off ("`noemptymatch`") by default. See `help regexp`.

Vertica's matching the 0-length empty string at the beginning is normal behavior for most regex dialects that I know, including anything Perl-like.

To get the same behavior as Vertica, where it can match 0-length strings, pass the `'emptymatch'` option in your `regexp` call. Also pass `'once'` to prevent it from matching the empty spaces between each and every character in your string.

```
[a,b,c,d] = regexp('JJJ123', '\d*', 'emptymatch', 'once')
```